# libxml2 on iOS causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when parsing HTML with HTMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, libxml2

I've been working on a project that uses libxml2 HTMLParser module to parse webpage HTML on iOS. I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error from libxml2's htmlParseDocument whenever I try to parse a webpage that contains the line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

If I strip this line out of the HTML, parsing works perfectly.

Also note, I am using the DTHTMLParser class to bind the libxml2 SAX callbacks to Objective-C code.

Since EXC_BAD_ACCESS in htmlParseDocument isn't much to go on, I've built a sample Xcode project that reproduces the error. I made it in Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion targeted for iOS 5.1. First it parses an HTML file that doesn't contain the offending line, then it attempts to parse the document with the offending line and crashes. You can download it here: http://michaelmanesh.com/code/libxml2-crash.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in DTHTMLParser was that apparently the method to prepare the c-callbacks in libxml did not set the function pointer for the function to call when a processing instruction is encountered to NULL. Because of this the processing instruction caused libxml2 to try to call a function at some random address causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I fixed the problem in DTHTMLParser by implementing support for an optional delegate method to be called for when a processing instruction is encountered or NULL in the handler struct if this is not implemented in the delegate.

Comment: Here's the change: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation/commit/bdf89f2aa092b5b3aeb1ae4af73ec0ac46db0f68

Answer (score 0):

I think LibXML mistakenly picks it up as a *processing instruction* which has nearly identical syntax.  Libxml treats every line that has `<?` in it as a processing instruction.  Though I can't quite pinpoint exactly what is going wrong.  If you remove the question marks, it will parse as a regular element and you will get the attributes in the `parser:didStartElement:attributes:` callback method.  If you put a space in between the question mark and the xml (`<? xml`) it will come back in the `parser:foundCharacters` method.  I don't know what your requirements are, but those are two ways to make it not crash.

Comment: Interesting, but this means you need to do two passes on your HTML: one to simply check for anything that looks like a processing instruction (since if you're right, a processing instruction anywhere in the HTML could cause this crash), and then the second to actually do the HTML parsing.

At least it seems to confirm that this is a bug in libxml2.

Comment: It certainly looks that way.  That's odd because libxml is an XML parser first, and processing instructions are irrelevant to HTML but relevant to XML.  However, the combination of `<?` and any a-zA-Z character appear to crash without fail.  Numbers and symbols work fine (I notice the libXML source does an IS_CHAR check often when it parses processing instructions).